# Recipient is Unable to Open Attachments where Email Attachment is sent from oracle

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am able to receive mail with attachment but I am not able to open it(Image file).
It shows as "wrong file format".

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where you can't see it? In plsqldeveloper?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  As a 1st time poster, please read [ask].  If you want someone to help you with a problem, please provide as much relevant detail as possible.